# Coefficient variation in Objective Function in Mixed Integer programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

Assume we have the following Mixed Integer programming.

MIP 1) $Z1=$ Max $Ax+By$

s.t

$Cx+Dy<=E$

$x>=0$ and $y: {0,1}$

Now, assume we have the same MIP, and I just converted A to A'

MIP2) $Z2=$ Max $A'x+By$

s.t.,

$Cx+Dy<=E$

$x>=0$ and $y: {0,1}$

My question is that if we can determine a bound for the difference of optimal solution of $Z1$ and $Z2$

i.e., $Z1^*-Z2^* <= Upper bound$

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: Using what information? With a simple flip on the sign of $A$, you can have an infinite difference as the problem can become unbounded.

Comment: Thank you for your note. In fact, $ A'=A+error $. In fact, I want to find a function with which I can bound the difference of optimal objective values of Z2 and Z1 i.e., $Z2^*-Z1^*<=function (error)$

Comment: Still, $x$ scalar and $A=-\epsilon$ and error larger than $\epsilon$ can lead to the same behavior. You will not find any generic bound of this type

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. So, if $error>=0$ and $A>=0$ then we'll not have this unbounded issue. In that case, do you think we can find an upper bound for $Z2^*-Z1^*$?

Comment: Are you looking for bounds for a particular instance, or for instances of this type (possibly with addition info such as non-negativity)

Comment: Instances of this type. In fact, in my case, $error >=0 $ and $A>=0$, also the size of error is much smaller than the size of A. It is possible to define a bound for the error component as well. And, I can further simply it by assuming that all error components are the same.

Comment: I found this paper quite useful: http://repository.cmu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1180&context=tepper